# Is it possible to iterate through the items in an ADT Linked List, from the client application in Java?

Tags: java, loops, oop, iterator, abstract-data-type

I've been tasked with implementing an ADT for a deck of 52 cards. I have four files:

- `Stack.java` (an interface)
- `Deck.java` (which implements Stack)
- `Card.java` (a simple object class with constructors, a toString method and get & set methods)
- `CardForce.java` (the client application, where Deck is instantiated and iteratively populated with Card object references)

I need the program to display all the cards in the deck, which I've done in the Deck class like so:

```
public void show() {
        Node current = topNode;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.println(current.getData());
            current = current.getNext();
        }
}
```

This method is called in the CardForce client app simply as `deck.show()` - deck being the name of the variable of type Deck as such:

```
public static void testCardForceOperations() {
        Stack<Card> deck = new Deck<Card>();

        System.out.println("Adding 3♤, 4♡, 5♢, 6♧, 7♤, 8♡, 9♢, 10♧ to deck:");

        Card card;

        card = new Card(Card.Suit.SPADES, Card.Value.THREE);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.HEARTS, Card.Value.FOUR);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.DIAMONDS, Card.Value.FIVE);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.CLUBS, Card.Value.SIX);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.SPADES, Card.Value.SEVEN);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.HEARTS, Card.Value.EIGHT);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.DIAMONDS, Card.Value.NINE);
        deck.push(card);
        card = new Card(Card.Suit.CLUBS, Card.Value.TEN);
        deck.push(card);

        deck.show();
}
```

The code above is simply for testing purposes - to populate the ADT linked list with all 52 cards I use a for loop to create the Card objects.

The output I get is all of the Card objects references - rather than the cards themselves (e.g. `Card@677327b6 Card@14ae5a5 Card@7f31245a`  etc).

I understand why this is happening - the Deck linked list isn't storing human readable information - it's storing references to Card type objects - but have hit a wall as to how to go about using the output to print human-readable data.

I was wondering if perhaps it was possible to iterate through the items stored in the ADT Deck linked list, returning them 1 by 1 to the client app then calling `.toString()` on them?

I've also got the suspicion that my implementation of the Card class is incorrect - that I should possibly be populating the ADT linked list in the Deck class, rather than doing so in the client app.

Comment: Card@677327b6 Card@14ae5a5 Card@7f31245a - it's result work of method toString() in Object. Ovewrite method in your Card.    `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return  "somethings from Card like Card.Suit ..... +  Card.Value....."; 
    }`

Comment: Thank you, @Anatoly! That has done the trick when the suit and value variables of the Card object are int and/or String data types. I previously had created the enums Suit and Value and used those custom data types instead, but ran into trouble overriding the toString by returning the getters as a String, as my custom data types/enums couldn't be expressed as a String. I'm still trying to work it out but your suggestion is perfect!

Comment: My be useful Suit.HEARTS.toString() or for example 'code' public static enum Suit {
         SPADES, HEARTS;
         @Override
         public String toString() {
             return "Suit "+this.name();
         }
     } 'code'